# Nginx redirection for entire subfolder with screening for special characters

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have trouble making this work:

I need all links from

*.domain.com/category/**1***

redirect to

*.domain.com/#something-{"[**1**]":"[]"}

---

*.domain.com/category/**2***

redirect to

*.domain.com/#something-{"[**2**]":"[]"}

So I'm stuck on both making a regular expression and making proper screening for special characters:

So far did that:

```
    server_name 1.domain.com 2.domain.com 3.domain.com;
    
    location /^category/1$ {
          return 301 /%23something-{&quot;[1]&quot;:&quot;[]&quot;};
        }
    location /^category/2$ {
          return 301 /%23something-{&quot;[2]&quot;:&quot;[]&quot;};
        }
```

And it doesn't work actually and takes some 10 lines, cause I have 10 categories.

**And also I need to redirect /category/ itself to /**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless tries I just installed a redirection plugin.